# Logo disappears in mobile on iPhone and iPad (iOS devices)

Tags: css, iphone, ipad, mobile, zurb-foundation

I'm working on a responsive website using the latest version of Foundation, starting with their Orbit template.  So far, everything seems to be going beautifully.  When I view the website in a browser and drag the edge left, everything appears to resize as it should.  However, when I view the same website on my iPhone or iPad, the logo is a blank box with the image title tag inside.  Anyone run into this?  I'm sure it's something simple I'm overlooking, but I've never run into this problem in the past.

The site is here:
http://brookechao.com/test-peopleplaces/

EDITED BECAUSE I SOLVED IT:
I knew it would be something simple (especially since I wasn't seeing anyone else with the problem).  Turns out it was just a corrupt image file.  Resaving the image file from the original fixed the issue.  Don't know why that didn't occur to me earlier.  I guess I figured if it was showing up on the desktop, but not the mobile devices it was a device/media issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check javascript in your code and paste here code if you are looking for help.Mostly when you give iOS a javascript event like **onmouseover** or **onmouseout** it doesn't like it, mainly because when your finger is "mousing over" an element in iOS, mostly it  seems to reload images after hitting the back button in iOS.

Thats may not be answer but a suggestion.

Comment: The javascript files I am loading are jquery.js, foundation.js, modernizer.js, orbit.js, top bar.js.    

Which one do you need to see? I haven't changed anything in the javascript files, so not sure why it shouldn't work as it should, right out of the box.  

The only script in html is:
'<script>
      $(document).foundation();

      var doc = document.documentElement;
      doc.setAttribute('data-useragent', navigator.userAgent);
    </script>'  

This is not a case of going back or reloading. iOS will not load the header logo image at all - just leaves a box with title text inside it.